# Why does typing "One way they can fit it in" as a text message create a link to Google Maps?

Tags: sms, google-maps, instant-messaging, hyperlinks

Today I noticed that when I typed and sent "One way they can fit it in" in the Facebook Messenger app for Android, it created a link (underlining the text, see first image below). When I follow this link, it prompts me to open the Compass app or Google Maps.

I have found that it does not work on the Messenger app for iOS or Windows, but does work for other messaging apps within Android. When opening the link in Google maps, it responds with a message, "No results found" (see second image below).

Can anyone else reproduce this behaviour? Does anyone have any idea what Android feature might be causing this phenomenon?

**Edit:** I am on a Samsung S8, using Android Pie, although my friend can also see this on his Huawei P10. This behaviour happens on both Facebook Messenger and the default Samsung Messages app. I have tried several other similar phrases, but I have found that the general form of text that forms this link must begin with "one", end with "in", and have three or more words in between, one of which must be the word "way" (For example, "*One* foo bar *way* hello world *in*" creates a link).

[image: Typing "One way they can fit it in" on Facebook Messenger for Android]

[image: Result of opening link in Google maps]

Comment: I was able to reproduce on a Pixel 2, Android 10, latest version of Facebook Messenger. I wasn't able to determine anything in the logcat, but others may have better luck. My guess, assuming it isn't something nefarious is that it is some Q/A or dev test mechanism left on in production.

Comment: I'm also experiencing the same thing. There are many different words that, whenever they appear in a text, are underlined and link to Google Maps with the word in question in the search bar.